# Can't Start IIS Express: An error occurred attempting to determine the process id

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

When I try to start my ASP.Net Core 1.1 app, I'm receiving the following error:

> An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of Blah.exe which is hosting your application. An error occurred while sending the request.

---

I changed the `applicationUrl` port number from **44300** to **44301** in `launchSettings.json' and I was able to get it to start.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44301/",
      "sslPort": 44301
    }
}
```

---

Why did changing the port # make it work?  Where can I look to figure out why it wouldn't startup?

I ran [TCPViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) and I don't see `44300` in use.

Comment: Probably something else are using this port.

Comment: That's what I would think but according to TCPViewer, Resource Monitor and netstat that port is not in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstall and [re-install of IIS Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264) fixed it.

Turns out port `44300` wasn't bound to my IIS Express cert.  Bill Hiebert figured it out as documented in [this developer community issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/171756/iis-express-an-error-occurred-attempting-to-determ.html).

---

When I ran `netsh http show sslcert`, port 44300 wasn't listed.  I uninstalled and re-installed IIS Express and now it is listed.

```
SSL Certificate bindings: 
------------------------- 

IP:port                      : 0.0.0.0:44300
Certificate Hash             : somevalue
Application ID               : {someid}
Certificate Store Name       : MY
Verify Client Certificate Revocation : Enabled
Verify Revocation Using Cached Client Certificate Only : Disabled
Usage Check                  : Enabled
Revocation Freshness Time    : 0
URL Retrieval Timeout        : 0
Ctl Identifier               : (null)
Ctl Store Name               : (null)
DS Mapper Usage              : Disabled
Negotiate Client Certificate : Disabled
Reject Connections           : Disabled
Disable HTTP2                : Not Set
```